# Standards for safety car seatbelts locking condition

Tags: safety, car, standards

Is there an (international) standard which determines the condition when a car seat belt locks? Which standard is it? Does the standard determines a speed in m/s of the belt, such that it locks if this speed is exceeded or does it determine an acceleration in m/s^2? How are the values?

Is there also a standardized testing procedure to ensure that the values are satisfied?

Comment: You should check things like the British Standards, not sure of the American equivalent . Then the Construction & Use Regulations will also contain detail. All the detail is specified including the mounting point strength of the car body. Here is but one possible link: https://shop.bsigroup.com/ProductDetail?pid=000000000010059033